# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de una tabla dependiendo el valor de los datos de otra tabla sin que estas tengan algo en común?

Tags: sql, subconsultas

Tengo la tabla ciudades

```
create table ciudades(
  codigo number(2),
  nombre varchar2(20),
  primary key (codigo)
 );
```

y la tabla clientes

```
 create table clientes (
  codigo number(4),
  nombre varchar2(30),
  domicilio varchar2(30),
  codigociudad number(2) not null,
  primary key(codigo),
  constraint FK_clientes_ciudad
   foreign key (codigociudad)
   references ciudades(codigo)
   on delete cascade
 );

insert into ciudades values(1,'Cordoba');
 insert into ciudades values(2,'Cruz del Eje');
 insert into ciudades values(3,'Carlos Paz');
 insert into ciudades values(4,'La Falda');
 insert into ciudades values(5,'Villa Maria');

 insert into clientes values (100,'Lopez Marcos','Colon 111',1);
 insert into clientes values (101,'Lopez Hector','San Martin 222',1);
 insert into clientes values (105,'Perez Ana','San Martin 333',2);
 insert into clientes values (106,'Garcia Juan','Rivadavia 444',3);
 insert into clientes values (107,'Perez Luis','Sarmiento 555',3);
 insert into clientes values (110,'Gomez Ines','San Martin 666',4);
 insert into clientes values (111,'Torres Fabiola','Alem 777',5);
 insert into clientes values (112,'Garcia Luis','Sucre 888',5);
```

y debo listar los nombres de las ciudades de aquellos clientes cuyo domicilio es en calle "San Martin", empleando subconsulta.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo ?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrar que intentaste hasta ahora? las tablas si tienen algo en comun, la ciudad

Comment: Qué base de datos estás usando?

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes usar `inner join` relacionando la columna `codigociudad` de la tabla `clientes` con la columna `codigo` de la tabla `ciudades`, luego de eso filtrar donde la columna `domicilio` de la tabla `clientes` contenga `San Martin`.

```
select ciudades.nombre from ciudades
inner join clientes on ciudades.codigo = clientes.codigociudad 
where clientes.domicilio like '%San Martin%'
```

Con subconsultas tendrías que hacer un `select` de los clientes que estén en `San Martin` y sobre ese `select` hacer otro buscando los `codigociudad` que existan en `ciudades`:

```
select nombre
from ciudades
where codigo in (
    select codigociudad
    from clientes
    where domicilio like '%San Martin%'
    )
```

[Aquí puedes ver una prueba](https://rextester.com/AAZB86523)